# Listbox's selected value(s) placement in cells

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, selecteditem

I am trying to place the results from `ListBox1` to specific cells, `K29` to `K35`, in Worksheet `'Calculation Entry'`.  I have it so that one can highlight multiple selections, but I need to extract those selections and place them in the cells stated.

They are from a listbox populated by cells in another worksheet. I have the listbox created and populated, but am having trouble moving the text from the selected items to the cells listed above.

The help that I am looking for is the `VBA` code to tie to `ListBox1` that activates with `ListBox1_Click()`.

I have remedied this and am placing this code as per the request of a friend:

```
Range("K27").Select 
dim msg as String
dim ary(100) as string
ActiveCell.Clear 
With ListBox1 
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 
       If .Selected(i) Then 
           msg = msg & .List(i) & vbNewLine
           ary(j) = .List(i)
           j = j + 1 
       End If 
    Next i 
    Range("K27").Select 
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=0).Activate 
End With 
If msg = vbNullString Then 
   MsgBox "Nothing was selected! Are you sure that you don't want to replace any parts?!" 
  Exit Sub  
 Else Check = MsgBox("You selected:" & vbNewLine & msg & vbNewLine & "Are these selections correct?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Please confirm")
 Worksheets("Calculation Entry").Activate ActiveCell.Value = msg  
end if
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you have so far?

Comment: I appreciate all of the input from each of you!  I changed it so that I used a isnumber(search( function in the cell that I used to process these values, so I condensed the cell range into a single cell.  I added the code below:

Comment: Range("K27").Select
    ActiveCell.Clear
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                msg = msg & .List(i) & vbNewLine
                ary(j) = .List(i)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
            Range("K27").Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=0).Activate
End With
    If msg = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Nothing was selected!  Are you sure that you don't want to replace any parts?!"
        Exit Sub

Comment: Else
        Check = MsgBox("You selected:" & vbNewLine & msg & vbNewLine & _
                       "Are these selections correct?", _
                       vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Please confirm")
                Worksheets("Calculation Entry").Activate
                ActiveCell.Value = msg

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the above code?

Comment: I've reformatted it for you!

Answer (score 0):

I can get this to work by including an additional Control...

The simplest way I can see of solving this is to include some descriptive text with the ListBox ("Select required items and click 'Go'") and then include a command button (Cmd_go) with the caption "Go". This button has the logic ...

```
Private Sub Cmd_Go_Click()
  ListBox1_Click
End Sub
```